# How do I load a list of json objects from a .txt file?

Tags: python

I am trying to load a list of json objects from a text file that I have been given. When I try to do this I get the error "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 14826 (char 14825)". I believe that this is because each json object is wrapped in quotes and separated by a comma.

for example the file I am reading looks like this

```
"{'name': 'john', age: '17', sex: 'M', 'nums': [2, 3, 4]}","{'name': 'sam', age: '23', sex: 'F', 'nums': [2, 3, 4]}","{'name': 'max', age: '12', sex: 'M', 'nums': [2, 3, 4]}"
```

I have tried using json.loads() and ast.literal_eval(), but both give me the same problem. I have also tried replacing the "," with a , and nothing to see if that would make it the correct format but the same errors came up.

```py
data = []
with open("raw.txt", encoding = 'utf8') as f:
            data = f.read()

data = json.loads(data)
```

I am expecting to get a list of all of the json objects in the text file

Comment: You have extra `"` in your string which is causing both `ast.literal_eval` and `json.loads` to break

Comment: Why not just load this as a CSV and loop over each string and `json.loads()` that?

Comment: Sorry I am kind of inexperienced, so let me know if I am wrong, but wouldn't a loading it as a csv cause problems because of the commas within each json?

Comment: `sex` isn't a proper key, it should be `'sex'`

Comment: are you sure you may use keys 'name': 'john', age: '17', sex: ones with single quotes, then not and use " around obejct?

Comment: Regardless of what you do, the quotes around a dictionary simply won't work since it does not follow json syntax. I like the suggestion by @esqew above where you load it as a csv. However you choose to do it, you'll need to make sure the first and last quotes for each {} object are not actually part of the json you are parsing.

Comment: the string I put in the question is just an example, thank you for pointing that out, I will edit it now

Comment: @smarkhami Loading it as csv should be fine, each JSON value is just a text value, properly quoted for the csv format (but as others pointed, these text values aren't valid JSON in your example).

Comment: @Isaac `.split(',')` won't work as there are commas inside the quoted string `'name': 'john', age: '17'`

Comment: whoops, brain fart moment, thanks, I'll edit it.

Comment: Those strings are neither json nor python literals and it is not clear what syntax rules they follow. You need to clarify the syntax first, only after that you can find a way to parse it.

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual contents of the file into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You were right regarding the potential of the `ast` module for this task. Using your example (in which I corrected the `sex` and `age` keys quoting), you don't seems to have valid JSON values but it seems you have valid representations of  python `dict`s.

```py
data = '''"{'name': 'john', 'age': '17', 'sex': 'M', 'nums': [2, 3, 4]}","{'name': 'sam', 'age': '23', 'sex': 'F', 'nums': [2, 3, 4]}","{'name': 'max', 'age': '12', 'sex': 'M', 'nums': [2, 3, 4]}"'''
```

By adding parenthesis on the start/end of this string, it can be parsed as a `tuple` of string. Then each of these strings will be parsed as a python `dict` :

```py
import ast

b = ast.literal_eval('(' + data + ')')
b = [ast.literal_eval(elem) for elem in b]
```